# What was the birth year of Korach?

Tags: age, parshat-korach

We know from the text that he was son of Itzhar, son of Kehas, son of Levi. Is there a reference that talks about his age at any point, or his birth year?

Comment: Yes there is. Well not exactly but somewhere near. In the hagada of R shmuel hanagid he writes I cant quote here the full story except that the bnai levi didnt work because they never started to. The one expception was korach who did work. So since the shibud was 86 years as old as miryam hence her name which is similar to maror, korach was already working.

Comment: @cham So you are saying he was 86+ at the time of the Exodus, and since he likely would not start work before 14 years old, we are looking at 100+ at Exodus time? Please write it up as an answer and I will be glad to accept it, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Magid Meisharim in Shmos (Parsha) says that Korach was born when Moshe slay the Mitzri. There is close to Ten opinions as to how old Moshe was at that time (see Toras Shleimah ibid.)
Based on classic Midrashim Moshe was either 20 or 40. This would make Korach 42 or 62.

Comment: +1, very useful, although I doubt that this is as simple as it sounds -- more likely to do with *gilgulim* than with *pshat* -- *Shaar haGilgulim* writes that in that generation, Yisro, Korach and the *mitzri* were *gilgulim* of Kain...